# Ember-data: model refresh on DS.Store.createRecord

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

Embsters!

I am trying to figure out why **my model isn't refreshed after I create a new record and save it to the store.**

*My route computes the `model` as follows:*

```
model: function (params) {
  var postID = params.post_id,
      userID = this.get('session.currentUser.id');

  var post = this.store.findRecord('post', postID) ;

  var followings = this.store.query('post-following', {
      filter: { post: postID }
  }) ;
  var userFollowing = this.store.queryRecord('post-following', {
      filter: { post: postID, user: userID }
  }) ;

  return new Ember.RSVP.hash({
      post:          post,
      followings:    followings,
      userFollowing: userFollowing
  });
}
```

*My template then renders **a list** and **a button**:*

```
{{#each model.followings as |following|}}
    ...
{{/each}}

{{#if model.userFollowing}}
    <button {{action 'follow'}}>Follow</button>
{{else}}
    <button {{action 'unFollow'}}>Unfollow</button>
{{/if}}
```

*And my controller creates/deletes the relevant `post-following` record:*

```
actions: {
    follow: function () {
        var user = this.get('session.currentUser'),
            post = this.get('model.post') ;

        this.store.createRecord('post-following', {
            user: user,
            post: post
        }).save();
    },
    unFollow: function () {
        this.get('model.userFollowing').destroyRecord() ;
    }
}
```

*When I click the `[Follow]` button:*

- a successful `POST` request is sent
- the button **is not** updated
- the list **is not** updated

*When I (refresh the page then) click the `[Unfollow]` button:*

- a successful `DELETE` request is sent
- the button **is not** updated
- the list **is** updated

**Do you have any idea of what I'm doing wrong?**
Could it be a problem with my payload?

---

## EDIT: Solved!

Well, it sounds like I was expecting too much from ember.

The framework won't automatically update my `post-following`s array on `store.createRecord('post-following', {...})` call.

I then adjusted my controller logic to "manually" update my model:

```
// in follow action…
userFollowing.save().then( function(){
    var followings = store.query('post-following', {
        filter: { post: postID }
    }).then( function (followings) {
        _this.set('model.userFollowing', userFollowing);
        _this.set('model.followings', followings);
    }) ;
});
// in unFollow action…
userFollowing.destroyRecord().then( function () {
    _this.set('model.userFollowing', null);
    _this.notifyPropertyChange('model.followings') ;
});
```

**Please note** that my backend API design has been criticized by @duizendnegen (see comments). More best practices in [this article](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/rest-api-design-resource-modeling).

Thanks you for all your help !!!
Brou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these kind of questions, it really helps to have a smaller, replicated problem (e.g. through Ember Twiddle)

Fundamentally, the new `post-following` record doesn't match the `filter`: it is filtered for an attribute `{ post: 123 }` and your `post-following` object contains something in the lines of `{ post: { id: 123, name: "" } }`.  Moreover, your `post-following` object doesn't contain a property called `filter` or what it could be - i.e. the query it executes to the server are different than those you want to filter by on the client.

My approach here would be to, as a response to the `follow` and `unfollow` actions, update the `model`, both the `userFollowing` and `followings`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! **Fiddle:** I tried, but it sounds impossible to call `store.query` using a FixtureAdapter… // 

**Model:** My backend filtering logic is: `GET /postfollowings?filter[post]=123`. The `filter[…]` syntax gives a cleaner API separation between filtering, sorting, and metadata QS params. Could it mess with ember? // 

**Your approach:** That's what I was doing before. It visually worked, but raised a strange empty `{}` error when trying to set my `model.followings` property. I also felt like ember should be handling that refresh alone… Is it actually the good way to go?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you aren't re-setting the property `model` to point to the newly created object. You are always accessing the same `model` property, even after creating a new one.

First thing to be aware of is that, after the `model` hook in your route, the `setupController` hook is called that executes:

```
controller.set('model', resolvedModel)
```

meaning that the `model` property on your controller is, by default, set every time the route loads (the `model` hook resolves). However, this **doesn't happen** after you create a new record so you must do it explicitly:

```
let newModel = this.store.createRecord('post-following', {
  user: user,
  post: post
})

// since model.save() returns a promise
// we wait for a successfull save before
// re-setting the `model` property
newModel.save().then(() => {
  this.set('model', newModel);
});
```

For a more clear design, I would also recommend that you create an alias to the `model` property that more specifically describes your model or override the default behavior of `setupController` if you are also doing some initial setup on the controller. So either:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  // ...

  blog: Ember.computed.alias('model') // more descriptive model name   

  // ...
});
```

Or:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  // ...

  setupController(controller, resolvedModel) {
    controller.set('blog', resolvedModel); // more descriptive model name 
    // do other setup
  }

  // ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your tips and help! As mentioned to @duizendnegen, setting the model "manually" after my request was my previous approach. It visually worked, but raised a strange empty `{}` error when trying to set my `model.followings` property. I also felt like ember should be handling that refresh alone… Is it actually the good way to go?

Comment: Well, the code you show expects to display a model that you **create sometime later**. Thus it cannot know automatically that you did this unless you tell it explicitly. [Here's a good read](http://emberigniter.com/force-store-reload-data-api-backend/) that shows how ember-data caches the models by default and how to make it always reload.

Answer (score 0):

Your model is set when you enter the page. When changes are made, your model doesn't change. The only reason why the list is updated when you destroy the record is because it simply doesn't exist anymore. Reload the model after clicking the follow button or unfollow button, or manually change the values for the list/button.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! **I make ~10 requests in my model hook though**, so it doesn't feel really good to trigger a full model refresh. **Do you know how to trigger a *sub-model* refresh?** (i.e. `model.followings` and `model.userFollowing` only)

Comment: That is indeed possible in the way your model is constructed. You can use something like: this.store.query(<your params and other stuff>).then(result => { this.get ('currentModel').set('followings', result); })